# Dynamically change a background image depending on view port width

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is WordPress site that I'm updating. I have two images; one for larger screens and one for smaller screens/mobiles.

I'm aware I can do this through CSS, but the background images are intended to be changed by the user who don't have access to the CSS. I have some custom fields created on the Wordpress that allows them to easily change the images.

At the moment I have this in the PHP page, which only works for one image:

```
<div class="block block--overlay" style="background-image: url('<?php echo theme('background_image', 'url'); ?>');">
</div>
```

What's the best way to have something like this?

```
<div class="block block--overlay" style="background-image: url('<?php if_large screen: echo theme('background_image', 'url') else echo theme('mobile_background_image', 'url'); ?>');">
</div>
```

I've read about the wp_is_mobile() function and that it's not very reliable, and doesn't work responsively.

What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a css variable for esktop and mobile versions, and use this variables in css `@media` queries.

the php will look like this:

```
<div style="--desktop: url('<?php echo 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/400'; ?>'); --mobile: url('<?php echo 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/600'; ?>')"></div>
```

The output should be like this:

```css
:root {
  --desktop: "placeholder-url";
  --mobile: "placeholder-url";
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
@media screen and (max-width:520px) {
div {
  background-image: var(--mobile);
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:520px) {
div {
  background-image: var(--desktop);
}
}
```

```html
<div style="--desktop: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/400'); --mobile: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/600')"></div>
```